# GTK equivalent to MS Spy++

Tags: software-recommendation, gtk

Spy++ comes with paid version of MS Visual Studio as

> utility that gives you a graphical view of the system’s processes, threads, windows, and window messages.

[image]

and it's not only utility on Win32 that offers this feature, but I use it as popular example.

It lists all UI elements of all running applications, and user can use "Find Tool" to locate UI element of interest and get response dialog with versatile information about that object, like UI control name, text contents, and many other data of potential interest to a programmer.

I'm interested in similar GTK application which can at least return GTK UI element (widget) name and extracted text contents of that element of arbitrary running process.

I couldn't find anything related using Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found g-inspector package by a quick google of "gtk inspector".

> g-inspector  invokes  a  GTK+  application and inspects its objects
>   and data.

Haven't tried it out, though.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in Synaptic. It inspects program that user passes as argument. I tried first with `nautilus` and it crashed. I tried then on `sonata` (mpd player) and it works like a nice program. I couldn't find a way to extract text contents out of example widget thou. If no other alternatives are suggested, I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 3):

I found another tool (it's listed in Synaptic), so I'll post it as answer in case others are interested in this feature - [GTK Parasite](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite/):

> If you've used Firebug, it's sort of like that, but for GTK+
>   applications.